# Site Time Running ahead

Tags: php, time

I know this has to be a crazy question, but my site has been right on time for years, now the time is 20 minutes ahead of what it should be.  I first noticed one day it way 17 minutes fast, but has now progressed to 20 minutes fast.  If I run this simple program:

```
<?php

echo date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
phpinfo();
 ?>
```

I get a time that is 20 minutes fast.  Is it my site or the server?
I am set: date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London").  Thanks for any help

Comment: Your server's clock is incorrect.

Comment: thank you very much - saves me time tearing apart the code

Comment: Use NTP to keep it in check

Comment: How would you do that in php - any examples?

Comment: This is not a PHP thing. Look it up to set this up for your particular OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if the issue is either server time or php by entering a terminal and typing the `date` command.

1. If the date is correct, then the issue is PHP (highly unlikely).
2. If it is not, which is probably the case, your issue is server time,
   not PHP. This is more of a server question, but in most Linux server
   distributions you have to install ntpd (network time daemon). Then
   start the ntp service and force a time update (if it doesn't do it
   automatically.)

This varies from distribution to distribution so I can't tell you exactly how to do it without knowing your stack.